# How do I pass an error message from C to Go?

Tags: go, cgo

I want to pass an error message from C code to Go stack. How I can accomplish this using an out parameter?

I'd really thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: `errno` errors are returned automatically, and any "error" parameters work like any other parameter. Can you better describe what problem you're having?

Comment: I have a C function that returns an integer value. Sometimes the function generates an error and I want to check that error from my caller function which is written in Go. In order do that, I want to get the error string out from C function using an out parameter. I've been trying to pass char pointer from my go function and fill that from c function. It does not work.

Comment: "It does not work" is not enough for us to diagnose what might be wrong. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any C function (even void functions) may be called in a multiple
>   assignment context to retrieve both the return value (if any) and the
>   C errno variable as an error (use _ to skip the result value if the
>   function returns void).

Then in your c code all you have to do is to set the “global” errno variable.

```
package main


// #include <errno.h>
// int fortytwo()
// {
//      errno = ENOENT;
//      return 42;
// }
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {

    n, err = C.fortytwo()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to retrieve the error string. Not the error code.

Comment: Then you have to pass a string by reference from Go to C and populate it with your error msg accordingly.